# Side Radial Menu in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Please how to create Side Radial Menu in flutter like a picture and make rolling when user tap in it

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you found out solution?

Comment: I'll try to deal with the problem tomorrow, I have an idea, but does the circle have to be scalable like in the video, this will be much more difficult, or can  the circle also have a fixed size

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by using a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html), [Transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html), trigonometry and some clipping with [ClipRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html).

Using `GestureDetector`, it is possible to see the drag distance that a user inputs. This can be used to determine how much to rotate the widgets.

Using `Transform`, it is possible to move widgets to specific locations.

Trigonometry is used to determine the position of the widgets to the centre of the circle.

Using `ClipRect`, it is possible to clip out the left side of the widgets.

It is possible to reverse scroll direction by instead taking the distance of the drag be turned negative.

Here is the code to make a rotating menu that uses a **custom widget** that I have recently created for answering this question(Add more Widgets to the Widget list if you want):

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body:CircularScrollView(//wrap this with align if you want it to be aligned to the right of the screen
          [//add more widgets or remove as you'd like
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},//insert function when icon is tapped
              child: Container(
                child: Center(child: Text('a')),
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},//insert function when icon is tapped
              child: Container(
                child: Center(child: Text('b')),
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},//insert function when icon is tapped
              child: Container(
                child: Center(child: Text('c')),
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},//insert function when icon is tapped
              child: Container(
                child: Center(child: Text('d')),
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},//insert function when icon is tapped
              child: Container(
                child: Center(child: Text('e')),
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          radius: 100,
          padding: 0,//add double the radius entered to clip out the right side
          itemMaxHeight: 20,//effects clipping border height
          itemMaxWidth: 20,//effects clipping border width
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class CircularScrollView extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> items;
  final double radius;
  final double itemMaxHeight;
  final double itemMaxWidth;
  final double padding;
  final bool reverse;
  CircularScrollView(this.items, {Key key, this.radius=10, this.itemMaxHeight=0, this.itemMaxWidth=0, this.padding=0, this.reverse=false}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CircularScrollViewState createState() => _CircularScrollViewState();
}

class _CircularScrollViewState extends State<CircularScrollView> {
  double lastPosition;
  List<Widget> transformItems= [];
  double degreesRotated = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _calculateTransformItems();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  void _calculateTransformItems(){
    transformItems= [];
    for(int i = 0; i<widget.items.length; i++){
      double startAngle = (i/widget.items.length)*2*math.pi;
      double currentAngle = degreesRotated+startAngle;
      transformItems.add(
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(
            (widget.radius)*math.cos(currentAngle),
            (widget.radius)*math.sin(currentAngle),
          ),
          child: widget.items[i],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  void _calculateScroll(DragUpdateDetails details){
    if (lastPosition == null){
      lastPosition = details.localPosition.dy;
      return;
    }
    double distance = details.localPosition.dy - lastPosition;
    double distanceWithReversal = widget.reverse?-distance:distance;
    lastPosition =details.localPosition.dy;
    degreesRotated += distanceWithReversal/(widget.radius);
    _calculateTransformItems();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        height: widget.radius*2+widget.itemMaxHeight,
        width: widget.radius*2 + widget.itemMaxWidth,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragUpdate: (details)=>setState((){_calculateScroll(details);}),
          onVerticalDragEnd: (details){lastPosition=null;},
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: ClipRect(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: widget.padding),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: transformItems,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When using this code, do not modify the insides of the custom widget unless you know exactly what that section of the code does. When aligning the widget, please instead wrap the custom widget from the outside.

Comment: thanks a lot :) scrollPhysic is not correct when i change align to `centerRight`

Comment: and how can i found out center item like with this screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDv0Y.jpg

Comment: I don't understand the first comment, but I'll try to answer it. Make sure to not change the code in the custom CircularScrollView widget. Wrap the custom widget instead with align or what you want. For your second comment, I have edited the code to make it possible to centre the item. You should put in the padding parameter: `(the parent widget width that you want to make it the centre of)/2 - (the values of the radius)`. The '-' symbol is the subtract symbol just to clarify.

Comment: thanks a lot, when i change `alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,` to `alignment: Alignment.centerRight,` scrolling direction is wise versa

Comment: please see this screen video https://imgur.com/a/T2YDVwm

Comment: I've already put a reverse parameter in the custom widget. Just set it to true. This way you could have it rotate counter-clockwise when scrolling down

Comment: i still have a problem when i try to have that in right side of screen, problem is this widget don't snap to right screen. please see this screen shot: https://imgur.com/a/H1kXXUO

Comment: Try not using alignment.centerRight directly in the custom widget. Instead, use enough padding so the right side is clipped. Then wrap the entire widget with an Align widget with the align parameter of alignment.centerRight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223708/discussion-between-harry-and-doldurma).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this package, [circle_wheel_scroll](https://pub.dev/packages/circle_wheel_scroll), move around this widget inside Stack, place with Positioned with negative left position if necessary.

```
CircleListScrollView(
              physics: CircleFixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
              axis: Axis.horizontal,
              itemExtent: 80,
              children: List.generate(20, _buildItem),
              radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
            ),
```

or this [listwheelscrollview](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/listwheelscrollview-widget-in-flutter/)

```
ListWheelScrollView( 
        itemExtent: 100, 
          
        // diameterRatio: 1.6, 
        // offAxisFraction: -0.4, 
        // squeeze: 0.8, 
        clipToSize: true, 
       children: <Widget>[ 
         RaisedButton(onPressed:null , 
       child: Text("Item 1",textAlign:TextAlign.start, 
            style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),),) , 
       RaisedButton(onPressed:null , 
       child: Text("Item 2",textAlign:TextAlign.center, 
            style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),),) , 
       RaisedButton(onPressed:null , 
       child: Text("Item 3",textAlign:TextAlign.center, 
            style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),),) , 
       RaisedButton(onPressed:null , 
       child: Text("Item 4",textAlign:TextAlign.center, 
            style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),),) , 
       RaisedButton(onPressed:null , 
       child: Text("Item 5",textAlign:TextAlign.center, 
            style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),),) , 
       RaisedButton(onPressed:null , 
       child: Text("Item 6",textAlign:TextAlign.center, 
            style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),),) , 
       RaisedButton(onPressed:null , 
       child: Text("Item 7",textAlign:TextAlign.center, 
            style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),),) , 
       RaisedButton(onPressed:null , 
       child: Text("Item 8",textAlign:TextAlign.center, 
            style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),),) , 
       ], 
      ),
```